# Free WordPress plugins for membership?

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I'm looking to create a membership-based website and I'm new to WordPress so its been a headache trying to look for free plugins that can

creates 3 levels of membership (non-members, members, and premium members)
limit access to certain pages/functionality of the site to members/premium members
Also can't find a good plugin for customizable registration form

Comment: Closing as "not a real question." You appear to be asking us to do a search for you. If you edit your question to detail where you've already looked and why possible solutions you've rejected (and why) I will reopen it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you, by any chance, look up "wordpress membership plugin" on Google?  The first link is for the [Membership](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/membership/) plugin on WordPress.org.  You only need 2 levels of membership (members and premium), as regular users will be non-members by default.  I suggest you do a Google search for "wordpress custom user registration" as well, because you'll find a free plugin for your second issue there.

tl;dr - LMGTFY